# C calling(by JNI) Java that calls a DLL(by SWIG)

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I use JNI to make C calls to Java classes. 
One of the Java classes loads a DLL and using SWIG generated code makes calls to that DLL.

The problem is: when I call in C the Java class that calls the DLL I get nothing, it's not working.

Unfortunatelly I cannot see the error that lies behind.

How can I solve this?
Thank you!

Here is the code that I use:

```
 /*
 * java method that loads the DLL and that is called from C
 * in the function "createInstance"(see below)
*/
public void loadIsystem(){
    System.load("c:\\_MksProj\\TestHarness\\lib\\IConnectJNI.dll");
    //System.loadLibrary(IConnectJNI);
    ConnectionMgr connection = new ConnectionMgr();
}

/*
 * the ConnectionMgr constructor
 * makes a call to the SWIG created wrapper "connectJNI"
 * and constructs the object. The most recently DLL is used.
 * here the call gets broken
 */
  public ConnectionMgr() {
      this(connectJNI.new_ConnectionMgr__SWIG_0(), true);
      //System.out.println("connectJNI.new_ConnectionMgr__SWIG_0()");
  }


  /*C code that calls the Java method(the env var is already instantiated)
  *the call gets broken when the "connection" instance is created:
  *ConnectionMgr connection = new ConnectionMgr();
  *in the loadSystem method
  */
  jobject createInstance(JNIEnv* env, char * className, char * contsructorSignature, ...)
  {
    jclass myclz = (*env)->FindClass(env, className);
    jmethodID cons = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, myclz, "<init>", contsructorSignature);
    jobject scObject = (*env)->NewObject(env, myclz, cons);

    printf("class: %d\n", myclz);
    printf("constructor: %d\n", cons);
    printf("instance: %d\n", scObject);

    jmethodID scMethod1 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, myclz, "loadIsystem", "()V");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, scObject, scMethod1);

    return scObject;
  }
```

Could be related tp this issue:
[call Java from Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/618)

Comment: Could you provide some more info?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific: "I get nothing, it's not working" is too vague. Can you list the steps you are taking, and the output of each step?

Comment: I have added more info related to this and updated the question, thank you